# Is it possible to query over specific document ids in firestore?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

So, I have userProject collection with projectId and userId. I get all projects of some specific user by using

```
query = db.Collection("userProject").Where("user_id","==",userId)
```

Now, I get projectIds of the related user. But since there can be many project ids(>30), I can't  use "in" operator like

```
query = db.Collection("project").Where("id","in",projectIds)
```

One solution I can think of is making docRefs with those ids

```
for _, id := range projectIds {
    docRefs = append(docRefs, db.Collection("project").Doc(id))
}
```

and then use

```
db.GetAll(context.Background(), docrefs)
```

But i have to use filters and pagination in those specific projects. So I need to make a query, so that I can later use `StartAfter`, `Limit` and `Where` on same query. How can i achieve that in firestore with golang?

Answer (score 1):

With your current schema, what you're trying to do isn't possible (pagination on a large, known list of items).

The easiest thing to do is duplicate the user id into the documents in the projects collection, and just query that collection filtering on user id. Duplicating data like this (denormalization) is very common in nosql type databases in order to enable more efficient queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have one confusion, not just the user_id, If I have other fields in userProject collection, I could use users as array of object inside project collection with properties user_id, role, ... But when I have to get all projects where user is involved, I have to know the user's internal properties inside project to use `array-contains` but the user may have one role in one project and another in other project. How can I model that?

Comment: This sounds like new problem.  Please post a new question explaining in detail what you're trying to do.